# How to find the newest entry for in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have table for recording client deposit, like this

```
Client_ID,deposit_amount,Time 

1 , 200 , 2014-03-27 05:32:10

2 , 500 , 2014-03-27 06:32:10

1 , 700 , 2014-03-28 04:24:26
```

I want to output like

```
2 , 500 , 2014-03-27 06:32:10

1 , 700 , 2014-03-28 04:24:26
```

How can I write a query to find the newest entry based on time.

Thank you

Comment: Is output correct or you want 
2 , 500 , 2014-03-27 06:32:10

1 , 900 , 2014-03-28 04:24:26
Sum of amount group by ID ?

Comment: Yes, Output is correct,  I want both clients' newest entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery-

```
select * from tablename a
where time=(select max(time) from tablename b where a.client_id=b.client_id)
```